# API calling Code working on localhost but not on server

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Locally code working fine but when uploaded to server showing 500 [Internal server error]
I have tried with single parameter but not working on live environment

- Parameters are in JSON.stringify(itemlist)

here is my ajax code:

```
 var itemlist = new Array();
 var item = {
        Fnumber: Fnumber, Snumber: Snumber, Flag: Flag, Page: _pageName, bulkupdate: false, sortText: $("#hdnsorting").val(), excel: false, filtCompany: $("#hdnfilterCompanies").val(), ShowDDLvalue: ddlValue, url: "localhost"
    }
    itemlist.push(item);
 $.ajax({
    url: '/CompanyContact/GetContacts',
    data: JSON.stringify(itemlist),
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {}
});
```

here is my controller method which is having FilterParameters model for parameters list:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetContacts(List<FilterParameters> item)
    {
        var List = _api.PostRequest<List<FilterParameters>, Contacts>(_baseAPIurl + "contacts", item, Convert.ToString(Session["AccessToken"]));
        return Json(List.Result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and here is my API call:

```
 public async Task<List<TOut>> PostRequest<TIn, TOut>(string uri, TIn content, string token)
    {
        List<TOut> DataList = new List<TOut>();
        try
        {
            using (var client2 = new HttpClient())
            {
                // token authorization
                client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var serialized = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var postTask = client2.PostAsJsonAsync<TIn>(uri, content);
                postTask.Wait();

                var result = postTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<TOut[]>();
                    readTask.Wait();
                    var Data = readTask.Result;
                    DataList = Data.ToList();
                    return DataList;
                }
                else
                {
                    return DataList = null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Also tried with sending all parameters of FilterParameters model object but failed.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell  more details about the 500 internal server error. In this way it would be easier to get to the root of issue

Comment: Hi Muhammad, While calling controller method from ajax, It is saying: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 [Internal server error] and sometimes getting 404 (Not Found) - Somewhere between controller and PostRequest method not working

Comment: if server is responding with a status of 404 it means it is not able to find your API that means you need to recheck you url which is building from client side

Comment: Or do your server knows the _baseapiurl or it is being set to the local one

Comment: I have set _baseapiurl in web config. URL is showing correct.
Do we need some settings for Live API's ?

Comment: Do your ajax call returns 404 or 500. Because you need to make your that if your http client gives 404 or your ajax request

Answer (score 0):

You experience error code 500 when there are Non-Nullable elements in the Model and you are missing a particular element in your post. So make sure you are mentioning all the elements in the "FilterParameters" object.  Also in your case, I think, there is no need to STRINGIFY the json array. send the json array directly.